# How to access to a json object value when the key like 'foo$bar'

Tags: javascript, json

I use the Youtube DATA Api and i receive a **JSON** which some object containing **key** like '**foo$bar**'.

So when i do this

```
entry.media$group
```

Javascript says that the value is **undefined**

Comment: If the value is undefined, then it doesn't exist, it's not a problem of accessing it, it's either not being sent, or not being parsed correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`entry['media$group']` should do it nicely.

Comment: There is no difference between `entry.media$group` and `entry['media$group']`, so if the OP's didn't work, yours won't either.

Comment: My url was wrong so the json received didn't contain the key media$group so i fixed it and now it's work fine.

Sorry for wasting your time...

Answer (score 1):

In js there are many ways to represent arrays and accessing it.

dot notation, entry.media$group is "syntactic sugar" for entry['media$group'] (as Kolink suggested)

*Example:*

```
var a = "green";

json_art= {
  "colors_translation": {
    "green": "verde"
  }
}
console.log(json_art.colors_translation.a); //not work

console.log(json_art.colors_translation[a]); //work
```